# saving value in database using nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am using `Nhibernate` and want to save value in database as below.
This is my store class

```
 public class Store
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Staff { get; set; }

        public Store()
        {            Staff = new Employee();
           }
}
```

and this is `employee class`

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    }
```

`storemap` as

```
  public class StoreMap:ClassMap<Store>
    {
        public StoreMap() 
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            HasOne(x => x.Staff).WithForeignKey("store");
             HasManyToMany(x => x.Products).Cascade.All();        }
    }
}
```

and `employee map`

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        References(x => x.Store  ).WithColumns("store");
        References(x => x.Store2).WithColumns("store2");

    }

}
```

in store table i am saving only name of the table. and in employee table i am saving `firstname`, `lastaname` of employee and also `foreignkey` of store to know that employee belong to which table. 
i write this line of code

```
using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var ali = new Employee { FirstName = "fname", LastName = "lname", store=2 };
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(ali);
                    trans.Commit();
                }
```

but this cannot implicitly convert int int models.store Employee.Store. this is only with store=2 first and `lastaname` are working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In store class add the `List` for employee

```
Public virtual Ilist<Employee> Employees {get; set;} // this list will save employees as per store
```

and add the following method for adding employee

```
public virtual void add_employee(Employee emp)
    {
        emp.Store = this; // its current store value
        employees.Add(emp);
    }
```

and call this method when adding new employee

```
using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var ali = new Employee { FirstName = "fname", LastName = "lname"};
               var stor = new Store { Id = "1", Name= "Firststore"}; // for creating new store 
               AddEmployees(stor,emp);
                session.SaveOrUpdate(ali);
                session.SaveOrUpdate(stor);
                trans.Commit();
            }

           Public void AddEmployees(Store str, Employee emp)
           {
              str.add_employee(emp);
           }
```

try this code. If any doubt just comment here

Edit:

When you dont want to use one to many, before adding employee create the store and add it to employee

```
var stor = new Store { Id = "1", Name= "Firststore"};


var ali = new Employee { FirstName = "fname", LastName = "lname" , Store = stor};
```

Comment: actually i want one to one relation between employee and store, and at this time i want to save value in only employee table not in store, only want to use store's id in employee, i done  it before as you guided, this work fine but i want one to one, when i m using one to one, is there need to create IList or not?  Thanks

Comment: then list dont need, so whats your problem with question ? any error or exception ?

Comment: var ali = new Employee { FirstName = "fname", LastName = "lname", Store=2 }; i m not able to assign value to store. fname and lname assign to first and last anem. but when try to assing 2 to store this results cannot implicitly convert int into models.store

Comment: you have declared it as "Store" in employee class. so you cant directly assign int value to that . and why you are assigning int value to store?

Comment: for relationship with store, this store is foreign key in employee table, because every employee belong to store, for that i m using store value please guide how can save an employee in table with store

Comment: did u find any difficult in using one to many option ? try my update